# Text wont center on phone

Tags: html, css

I have a weird problem here, the text and images aren't aligning to the center, I've been coding this site from scratch and it works pretty well when I test it on the computer, but when I try it on the phone it doesn't work. Here are the pictures (From the computer and the phone)

---------COMPUTER
[Computer's resized Firefox windows 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9doKq.png)

---------PHONE
[Phone's screenshot 1 - Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVLQg.jpg)

Here's my code, I've been using bootstrap and normal HTML, CSS and basic PHP and JavaScript

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default nav_menu_head">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default nav_menu_head">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
   <div class="navbar-header">

      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-10">
       <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand" rel="home">
        <img class="img-responsive logo" src="img/logo2.png"></a>

      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar_colapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
  </button>
     </div>


      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-md-6 text-justify-xs" id="myNavbar">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav_menu_head" >
  <li ><a href="index.php#empresa" >EMPRESA</a></li>
  <li ><a href="productos.php">PRODUCTO</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.php#contacto">CONTACTO</a></li>
<!--  <li ><a href="#">SOPORTE TÉCNICO</a></li -->
</ul>
</div>     
</div>
 </nav>
```

And here´s the CSS

```
.text_box{width: 100%; 
height: 200px;}
.navbar-header{float: none;}

.text-justify-xs {
text-align: center;
}

.img-responsive.menu_image{margin: 0 auto;}
.collapse.navbar-collapse.col-md-6.text-justify-xs {border-width: 0px;}
```

Comment: Just a hint... Check if ul, li (and optionally a) has display: block; and width: 100%; Maybe in mobile there are some other styles being applied that overwrite default definitions

Comment: i assume you're calling your css after calling botstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a mismatch between the `display` property values on your `ul`. It's not uncommon for browsers to have different default values. Try setting `display: block` on your `.nav_menu_head`.

Comment: It worked! Not in my phone for some reason but its now working on my co-worker´s phones

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
.text-justify-xs ul li a {
    text-align: center;
}
```

in your css

Comment: It didn´t work :/ I´ve also tried to place it in the 
.collapse.navbar-collapse.col-md-6.text-justify-xs ul li a 
class